# Installing SVJour on OSX / Mactex

Tags: installing, sv-classes

I've to install the SVJour3 class. In the readme it says "Copy svjour3.cls and svglov3.clo to a place where LaTeX can find them."

Where is this place on a Mac where I installed MacTex 2011 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following structure in your home folder:

```
[Home]/Library/texmf/tex/latex/svjour
```

(it should be clear what `[Home]` stands for).

You can do it from the Terminal with the single command line

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/svjour
```

Otherwise, open the Library folder and do "New Folder", naming it `texmf` (if not already present), then again for the other folders.

Then copy the files in the last one (`svjour`).

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this has been answered before...

Copy the classes intothe same folder as your main tex file. TeX will always look there first. This is ok if you need it only for one project.

If you need those classes more often find you texmf via the command line

`kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`

this should return something like

`.../home/username/texfm-local`

copy the files to this folder using the tex tree structure e.g.

`home/username/texmf-local/myclassfiles/myclass.cls`

after that run

`texhash`

on your command line to update the package database