# Springer svjour3

Tags: errors, journal, sv-classes

I had been already using LaTeX. Now I want to send my article to a Springer journal. Therefore I am using the `svjour3` template, but it gives me an error. It is like this:

LOG FILE :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.4.14) 1 DEC 2015 00:29
entering extended mode
**template.tex
(template.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fix-cm.sty"
Package: fix-cm 2014/09/29 v1.1s fixes to LaTeX
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
))
! LaTeX Error: File `svjour3.cls' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.3 \documentclass
[smallextended]{svjour3}
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
399 strings out of 493698
8603 string characters out of 3141962
52149 words of memory out of 3000000
3816 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
17i,0n,12p,166b,150s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently, your MikTeX distribution does not have `svjour3.cls` installed, which is quite natural, since it's available from the Springer website only.

Comment: These classes are not, I think, part of standard TeX distributions.  You need to install the package manually. Wherever you got the instructions to use this class should tell you where to get it. You can put it in the same directory as your `.tex` file and it will be found.

Comment: Follow the instructions here: [LaTeX Author Package for Springer journal publications with `spr-chicago` bibliography style](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html)

Comment: Related: [Installing SVJour on OSX / MacTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59216/5764)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still can not able to make my root path "TDS compliant directory ", after putting my desired .cls file in recommended folders. I am LaTeX beginner and using windows 8.1. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the [Springer class](https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates);
2. Follow the instructions listed in [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)

   If you want to avoid hassles, you can just place `svjour3.cls` in your working folder.

Comment: Dear Werner, Thank you. Unfortunately I am still can not able to make my root path "TDS compliant directory ", after putting my desired .cls file in recommended folders. I am LaTeX beginner and using windows 8.1. please help

Comment: @Amber: After you place the files in the respective folders, then you need to run `texhash` from the command line. Alternatively, if all else fails, just place the `.cls` in your working folder and things should compile without problem.